# Getting files out from an SVN backup with "no such revision" error

Tags: svn, backup

I have a backup of an SVN repository with the following dirs and a readme:

```
conf  dav  db  format  hooks  locks  README.txt
```

I'm trying to extract the files from it.

If I do `svn co file:///path/to/dir/` I get:

```
svn: No such revision 19755
```

If I run `svnadmin verify file:///path/to/dir/`, the SVN client runs through verifying all the revisions until I get to:

```
* Verified revision 1998.
* Verified revision 1999.
svnadmin: No such revision 2000
```

If I do `svn log file:///path/to/dir/` I get an output of all log entries with no errors, starting at r19755 and counting back to r1.

`svn export` gives me the same as `svn co`.

`svn co -r1999 file:///path/to/dir/` gives me the `svn: No such revision 19755` message again.

Is there any way I can get a working set of files out from here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately sounds that like your backup didn't work correctly...furthermore if you get messages during svn co -r1999 ..there is something wrong...

Have you tried to do a

```
svn list -r 1999 file:///SVNReposRoot/
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - that gives me `svn: No such revision 19755`

Comment: Have you given the repository root not a directory inside the repository...?

Comment: Hi.  Yes, have done.  I can do an SVN log okay so I think it can see the repo okay.  Any other ideas?